# How to code progress bar to set completion status in online course app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an online course app in flutter, and I need to code a progress bar depend on students completion of course, how do I do that in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question. Concretely, you can use a `LinearProgressIndicator` to show the progress. Store the progress inside the `State` of the overarching widget, and update it after a part is completed, which should update the progress bar accordingly.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html

You can then imagine something like this:

```dart
// In a stateful widget
double progress = 0.0;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(children: [
    LinearProgressIndicator(progress: progress),
    Expanded(
      child: MyCourseView(onMadeProgress: (newProgress) {
        // Using setState ensures this widget rebuilds
        setState(() => progress = newProgress);
      }),
    ),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i will have to research some right?